# Nodemailer - email send but not receive

Tags: email, nodemailer, feathersjs

I'm build an API with feathersjs and I need to send an email with an attachment.

The email seems to be send but I receive nothing.

In my mail.service.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.office365.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // secure:true for port 465, secure:false for port 587
  auth: {
    user: 'gil.felot@myaccount.com',
    pass: 'MyPassWord'
  }
});

// Check the connection to the service.
transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Server is ready to take our messages');
  }
});
```

Then in my hook

```
hook => {
    const file = hook.params.file;

    const email = {
      from: 'gil.felot@myaccount.com', // sender address
      to: 'mygmailaccount@gmail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Test Nodemailer', // Subject line
      // text: req.body.text, // plaintext body
      html: '<b>Hello world </b>', // html body
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: file.originalname,
          contents: new Buffer(file.buffer, 'base64'),
          encoding: 'base64'
        }
      ]
    };

    return hook.app.service('mail').create(email)
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log('Sent email', result);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

then I got

> Server is ready to take our messages
>
> Sent email
>
> Object {from: "gil.felot@myaccount.com", to: "mygmailaccount@gmail.com", subject: "Test Nodemailer", html: "**Hello world** "}

I have no idea how to check where the problem come from.

Comment: Some times it takes some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figure it out !

I needed to add the `transporter.sendMail()` inside the `mail.class.js` to trigger this action when I call `hook.app.service('mail').create(email)`

Working and the attachement file that is 0 byte in the mail but the good size inside my variable.

Answer (score 16):

I was missing the from part while creating a mail while I was able to send mail via google smtp but my own smtp was failing with the above configuration

Was working with google

```
var mailOptions = { to: email, subject: 'Forgot Password', html: mailData };
```

Working with my smtp as well:

```
var mailOptions = { from: 'serverName.com', to: email, subject: 'Forgot Password', html: mailData };
```

Consider adding name while defining `nodemailer` configuration as well

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
name: 'example.com' // <= Add this
host: 'smtp.example.email',
port: 587,
```

Comment: Many thanks! Missing `name` key in nodemailer configuration was the issue for me

Comment: in case of smtp connection uri append `/?name=example.com`

Comment: I wonder why is this not mentioned in the Nodemailer's official docs (as of Jan '23)

Answer (score 1):

For me this was what I realized; if the html does not have the html tags, then the email is not sent. i.e.

This template will work

```
<html>
 <body>
  Hello and welcome
 </body>
</html>
```

This template will not work:

```
 <body>
    Hello and welcome
 </body>
```

This is especially when sending to office365, refer to this other question here:
[Nodemailer doesn't send emails to outlook.office365 accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66015787/nodemailer-doesnt-send-emails-to-outlook-office365-accounts/71406329#71406329)