# Nodemailer doesn't send emails to outlook.office365 accounts

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nodemailer

I am trying to send emails from a gmail account to the receiver which is my university email outlook.office365 .
it works fine for gmail to gmail , gmail to outlook.live , gmail to yahoo

```
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export const send = async (to, from, subject, html) => {
  // let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: 'Example',
    service: 'gmail',
    secure : false,
    port : 587,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
    },
  });
  transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
    }
  });
  let info = await transporter.sendMail(
    {
      from,
      to  ,
      subject,
      html,
    },
    (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log(info)
    },
  );
  
};
```

Comment: Can you include information about if you checked spam messages. Notice that in office365 mail there is certain kinds of view where messages are shown filtered including spam/automated messages.

Comment: I checked and sent multiple times but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this was what I realized, when sending to office365, if the html does not have the html tags, then the email is not sent.
i.e.

This template **will work**

```
<html>
 <body>
  Hello and welcome
 </body>
</html>
```

This template **will not work:**

```
 <body>
    Hello and welcome
 </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's ok , I found a solution , apparently outlook doesn't accespt html in emails , if you change the html attribute to text , it will be sent .

Comment: I don't even think this is true

Comment: Apparently, I also realized when using nodemailer if you send type text, the  email is sent, but type html it fails, so this answer might have some context to it.

Comment: this is wrong please remove this

Comment: No, this definitely was true 2 years ago, you should probably not follow this if you're using a newer version